# Bring single item to top of list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given an arbitrary list of items, in a ul or set of divs, I would like to use the angular way to bring the selected item to the top of a list/display.

```
$scope.items = [{name: "Garfield", id: 1}, {name: "Simon", id: 2}, {name: "Whatever", id: 3}]
$scope.model = {selectedItemId: 3}
```

In the view, using ng-repeat

```
ul.items
  li.item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{selected: model.selectedItemId == item.id"
    div {{item.name}}
```

I would like the selected item to be filtered or sorted to the top of the list while leaving remaining order in tact using AngularJS approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is already nicely formatted as an array, you would use a custom filter.

Angular provides a lot of built in filters, but it's pretty easy to write your own.
I was going to put an example in here, but a search found a very nice example created by Sam Deering
[here](http://angularjs4u.com/filters/angularjs-orderby-bring-item-top/) that I really can't improve on.

For ease of access, here is relevant part of the code:

```
app.filter('currentUserToTop', function () {
    return function (users, current) {
        var newList = [];
        angular.forEach(users, function (u) {
            if (u.id == current) {
                newList.unshift(u);
            }
            else {
                newList.push(u);
            }
        });
        return newList;
    };
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/422V4/) is the fiddle associated with this example.